# Will ubuntu run on a WP8?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, windows-8, windows-phone

I recently bought a lumia 521 and was wondering if it would be able to run ubuntu touch. I did not see this question anywhere else, but please tell me if it is.

Comment: This question has already been asked. It doesn't matter if it's a [Lumia 710](http://askubuntu.com/questions/363812), a [Lumia 820](http://askubuntu.com/questions/328653) or an [iPhone](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-touch+iphone). Devices like tablets and smartphones are mostly closed platforms, where you can't simply install another operating system you like. The fact that you can install Linux on computers from your electronics discounter is rather an accident from the manufacturers point of view and an ongoing struggle for the community. (smartphones are rather a lost war.)